# обработка массива пользовательской функцией в perl

Tags: функции, perl

Как в функцию передать массив и что то с ним сделать в perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно передавать указатель на массив:

```
#!perl.exe -w
use strict;
use utf8;

our @array = qw(Мама мыла Вишну);

sub printArray{
    my ($ref) = @_;

    for my $element (@$ref) {
        print "$element\n";
    }
}

printArray(\@array);
```

См. [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)

Answer (score 0):

Пока гуглил или пытался воспроизвести проблему с бесконечным циклом(и конкретной загрузкой ЦП), или отказом вообще работать. нашел решение проблемы.

Ниже пример как в пользовательскую функцию передать массив.  И в данном случае его вывести.

```
#!perl.exe -w
#строка выше у вас может быть другой.

use strict;

my @array = ("Мама", "мыла", "Вишну");

sub readArray{
    my($val) = @_;
    for(my $i=0; $i < @$val ;$i++){ 
        print @$val[$i]."\n";
    }
}

readArray( \@array);
```

Суть в этом "$@"  это называется применить к ссылке операцию разименовывания.
А при вызове нужно передать ссылку на массив.
информацию нашел [тут: http://valera.asf.ru/perl/book/9/9.4.html](http://valera.asf.ru/perl/book/9/9.4.html)

Comment: Можно было не по ссылке передавать, а напрямую: `readArray(@array);`. И в самой функции: `my @val = @_;`

Comment: В целом, функцию можно укоротить: `sub readArray { print $_ . "\n" for (@_); }`.

Comment: спасибо за дополнения. я пока только изучаю все это.

Comment: Можно еще так  укоротить ;-) `perl -MData:Dumper -e "print Dumper(\@array)"`

Comment: @AlexanderFarber а что это значит, хоть бы объяснили :) я ведь только изучаю все это.

Comment: Вставляете в свой скрипт строку `use Data::Dumper;` и потом пользуетесь `print Dumper(....);` чтобы распечатавать всякие структуры (типа var_dump в PHP). Только этот метод всегда хочет **reference**, поэтому для массива надо было вызывать так `print Dumper(\@array);`

Comment: @AlexanderFarber Спасибо. теперь буду пользоваться и я тоже :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

sub a {
   $in = shift;

   foreach ( @{$in} ) {
      print $_;
   }

}
```